# Unwanted white space area when using float in two column layout in FireFox

Tags: html, css

I am having some problem with a two column layout in Fire Fox. In Chrome is looks as it should. But in Fire Fox I get a 50 pixel height white space area between the text and the menu, when I use float: left; for the left column and float: right; for the right column. I can't understand why and I searched for error in the CSS, but I cant find any and I don't know if I have done something wrong. I have used Fire Bug, but it's just like a dead area. Help is appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you add `overflow: hidden` to `#wrapper-body` the extra space is removed (on Firefox 12)

```
#wrapper-body {
    ...
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

---

screenshot:

[image]

Comment: I don't know but If I have to guess I imagine this is related to some floated elements

Comment: Your screenshoot is that taken from Internet Explorer? The fonts looks better than they do in Fire Fox. And in Chrome the fonts don't look good at all, despite it Google fonts. Do you happens to know why? And thanks for the help with the floating problem!

Comment: it's taken from Firefox12[it_IT]/MacOs and I suppose that font looking you see it depends on the quality of the screenshot I captured